# AngularJS stateprovider view templates

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs, view

```
WikiApp.config(function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('revision', {
        url: '/wiki',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'ListCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'wiki/wiki.tpl.html'
            },
            "sidebar-left": {
                templateUrl: 'wiki/wiki.sidebar-left.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'List articles' }
    })
```

This is what my Angular bit looks like and this is how I execute it inside of a template (`wiki.tpl.html`):

```
<div ui-view="sidebar-left"></div>
```

Now the `main` view works fine, but as I try to integrate the sidebar, it doesn't load, what am I doing wrong and how can I use more than one template in a single page like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
WikiApp.config(function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('revision', {
        url: '/wiki',
        views: {
            main: {
                controller: 'ListCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'wiki/wiki.tpl.html'
            },
            sidebarLeft: {
                templateUrl: 'wiki/wiki.sidebar-left.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'List articles' }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but making it camel case doesn't quite solve the issue. Also - it works as is if I put the `<div ui-view="sidebar-left"></div>` in the main `index.html` file next to `<div ui-view="main"></div>`, but not if in the template file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested templates you should implement that using sub-views. In your current example you are setting both templates as sibling templates.

I suggest you to create 2 states. Abstract view for the main template 'main' and another view 'main.wiki'. Route should be assigned to 'main.wiki' state ant it will inherit parameters from the main view (including template settings).

Hope that's clear.